# Connect with Snowsql

Tags: command-line, snowsql

I would like to set up Snowsql client so I can connct for the first time and run commands like PUT.

I dont know where to find exacte values of :

```
accountname = xxxx
username = xxxx
password = xxxx
```

When I run following command from Windows command prompt :

```
C:\Users\noureddine.ettalhi>snowsql -a ettalhi -u ettalhi
Password:
250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB. Verify the account name is correct: ettalhi.snowflakecomputing.com:443. HTTP 403: Forbidden
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!
```

It kept saying the mentioned error. so what value should I give for account ?

where are the steps to follow to use SnowSql for the first time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using snowsql client  you may also create profiles in the config files 
located at 
`.snowsql/config`

```
[connections.MY_DEV]
accountname = myco.us-east-1
username = myuserid
database = mydb
role = mydb_admin
schema =  myschema
warehouse = my_WH
```

Once you have set up a profile  this then you can specify the 
snowsql -c My_DEV will prompt for password .. just another way

Answer (score 2):

Use fully qualified account name i.e **Name** + **Regional Zone** + **Cloud Provider Name**

For example:

1. your account name is **oi12345**
2. Regional zone is **ca-central-1**
3. Cloud provider is **aws**

Then your fully qualified account name is **oi12345.ca-central-1.aws**

Now let's say your **userName** is **bestUser123**

Now your command should be:

`snowsql -a oi12345.ca-central-1.aws -u bestUser123`

Comment: This answer was for me a lot more helpful than the snowflake documentation

Comment: Ditto Arnaud. I've pored over the snowflake documentation and nowhere did it give this info. I assumed (wrongly) that clicking on "Copy account identifier" when hovering over the account in the bottom left of Snowsight would suffice. What's the point in "Copy account identifier" if it doesn't copy everything that you need to connect?

Answer (score 1):

The account name is a part of the URL used to access your snowflake account, in my case it is 
`vq985xx.ca-central-1.aws`
since my URL is 
`https://vq985xx.ca-central-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com`

This is explained in snowflake documentation , link :
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-log-in.html#step-1-log-into-snowsql

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are using the Canadian AWS Trial Instance:

```sql
/* 1 liner */
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT('SNOWSQL -A ', LOWER(CURRENT_ACCOUNT()), '.', LOWER(REPLACE(CURRENT_REGION(), 'AWS_', '')), '.AWS -U ', LOWER(CURRENT_USER())));
```

```sql
/* Formatted */
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT('SNOWSQL -A '
                  , LOWER(CURRENT_ACCOUNT())
                  , '.', LOWER(REPLACE(CURRENT_REGION(), 'AWS_', ''))
                  , '.AWS -U '
                  , LOWER(CURRENT_USER())
                   )
            );
```

Should return you something like:

> snowsql -a your_account_id_here.ca-central-1.aws -u your_user_name_here

1. Copy the result
2. Paste into powershell or command line
3. Enter your password
4. Wait ~10 seconds for it to connect

Answer (score -1):

To get accountname use CURRENT_USER() function that will return account name that you need to combine with region segment from this page https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-log-in.html#step-1-log-into-snowsql.